# Como alterar fonte de um codigo CSS de integração E-GOI/WP pronto?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Sou novo na área de programação Web e gostaria muito da ajuda de vocês sobre um problema que surgiu aqui! (Ja tentei o suporte).

Criei um site no WordPress no qual tem um **formulário de contato** vinculado ao E-goi, até aí tudo bem, porém, ao ver o **tamanho da fonte** do botão ("Quero Agendar Agora"), ficou muio pequena!

A página é essa aqui:

> <del>http://solangenutricoach.com.br/enfoco</del>
>   http://solangenutricoach.com.br/13sabotadores/

Código do formulário E-goi:

```js
var _egoiLoaderMulti = _egoiLoaderMulti || [];
var _egoiLoaderValues = [];

_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setForm", "9ebeDAje5q8N0H2the93d-c027"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setList", "9"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setResource", "0ce6ae0ea5282dae0d5957b75d7a02dd"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setUrl", "http://mkt.bitcoinalx.com/"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setType", "button"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setColor", "#00ff00"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setFontColor", "#ffffff"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setText", "QUERO AGENDAR AGORA"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setWidth", "320"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setHeight", "348"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setSubscriberCount", "false"]);
_egoiLoaderValues.push(["_setSubscriberLabel", "contatos"]);

_egoiLoaderMulti.push(_egoiLoaderValues);

(function() {
  var egoi = document.createElement("script"); egoi.type = "text/javascript"; egoi.async = true;
  egoi.src = "http://mkt.bitcoinalx.com/include/javascript/egoi.js";
  var e = document.getElementById("script_9ebeDAje5q8N0H2the93d-c027"); e.parentNode.insertBefore(egoi, e);
})();
```

```html
<div id="a9ebeDAje5q8N0H2the93d-c027"></div>

<!--Paste this code where you want the button to appear-->
<div class="egoi_button" id="b9ebeDAje5q8N0H2the93d-c027"></div>
```

A pergunta é a seguinte: Como criar um elemento para alterar somente o tamanho da fonte do botão "Quero Agendar Agora"?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow Alexsandro. Evite escrever em CAIXA ALTA nas mensagens. De qualquer forma, acessei aqui o site que você mencionou e o botão <QUERO  AGENDAR AGORA> está com a fonte grande, eu achei proporcional, pelo menos.

Comment: Eu errei o link! é esse aqui http://solangenutricoach.com.br/13sabotadores/

Comment: Eu errei o link! é esse aqui http://solangenutricoach.com.br/13sabotadores/

Comment: Então é só você copiar o mesmo código da outra página, que está funcionando.

Comment: Pedro seguinte: Deixa eu te explicar melhor! A pagina anterior não está do jeito que quero que é Um POPUP... já a ultima que mandei está do jeito que quero mas somente o tamanho da fonte que não conseguir mudar! Compreendeu?